# Prevent unsafe unicode character characters in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a content editable div in one of my forms and a user created a line separator unicode character represented by \u2028. This caused Javascript to throw an  "Illegal Character" error. What is the best way to prevent these kinds of characters form being submitted?

**Bad characters:**
`\u0000-\u001f \u007f-\u009f \u00ad \u0600-\u0604 \u070f \u17b4 \u17b5 \u200c-\u200f \u2028-\u202f \u2060-\u206f \ufeff \ufff0-\uffff`

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to figure out why your JavaScript is breaking instead of blacklisting them?

Comment: Those characters are generally unsafe: http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#unsafe

Comment: It'd be best to do it serverside. You could write a regex to match them.

Comment: It’s difficult to see what could be a good reason to blacklist U+00AD SOFT HYPHEN for example. On the other hand, what is the technical problem with implementing a blacklist (in client-side JavaScript)? Can’t you just match the element content against a regexp containing the forbidden characters, after any change of the content? Or just when copying the content to a hidden field for form submission, if instant checking is not needed/desired.